# Taptic Engine stopped working on my iPhone 6s

Tags: iphone, haptic-feedback, ios

One fine day, the Taptic engine on my iPhone 6s decided to stop working. The phone is being used normally and there was no mishandling, dropping, jerks/shocks to the device or exposure to moisture/liquid.

This has happened previously a couple of times, where restarting the device has generally resolved the problem, but not this time. It has been around 4-5 days and the Taptic engine simply won't give any feedback when force touching an app icon, receiving a call etc.

I have tried restarting the device multiple times, and have also reset the device entirely, but to no avail.

I am running iOS 12.1.4 (current as of this writing). How do I resolve the issue?

Comment: I think this is a servicing issue and hardware issue that needs to be checked at the Apple Store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the device inspected at an Apple authorized service provider. Post inspection, I was told that the Taptic Engine motor has failed. The only available resolution when the Taptic Engine motor fails is a replacement with a new one.

I got the same replaced and the device is working normally after that.